# Immanuel Kant quote

Tags: translation, phrase

Immanuel Kant once said something along the lines of ''You can judge a man's character by the way he treats animals''.

I can find many different versions/paraphrases of this quote in English online but I can't find it in Chinese.

Can anyone find it ?

An accurate translation would be a good start but ideally I'd like to find some source.

Answer (score 2):

I find 2 versions of translation for this quote on the Chinese Internet, both of them are widely used to teach children to be kind to animals.

```
1. 从一个人对待动物的态度中，我们可以略晓其善心
```

```
2. 我们通过一个人对待动物的态度来判断他的心地
```

Answer (score 0):

> *An accurate translation would be a good start but ideally I'd like to find some source.*

Sounds like you want to cite this phrase from some authoritative source.

> 你可以憑一個男人對待動物的方式去判斷他的品格

> You can judge a man’s character by the way he treats animals

> Source: [Google Translate](https://translate.google.ca/?sl=zh-CN&tl=en&text=%E4%BD%A0%E5%8F%AF%E4%BB%A5%E6%86%91%E4%B8%80%E5%80%8B%E7%94%B7%E4%BA%BA%E5%B0%8D%E5%BE%85%E5%8B%95%E7%89%A9%E7%9A%84%E6%96%B9%E5%BC%8F%E5%8E%BB%E5%88%A4%E6%96%B7%E4%BB%96%E7%9A%84%E5%93%81%E6%A0%BC&op=translate)

Even if you found a translation from a published book, there might still be other authoritative source that translated it differently.

Answer (score -2):

Having just watched a neighbour slaughter a dog, I ask myself this question:

看一个人对待小动物的好坏，是否能看出这个人对待人的好坏？(Beware of neighbours bearing knives!)

Comment: omg  where’re you? did you call the police?

Comment: 中国江苏省南京市。I was the same little black dog I saw wandering around here recently.